# Can we use Plotly Express to plot zip codes?

Tags: python, python-3.x, plotly

I'm using the code from this link.

https://devskrol.com/2021/12/27/choropleth-maps-using-python/

Here's my actual code.

```
import plotly.express as px
 
from urllib.request import urlopen
import json
with urlopen('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/plotly/datasets/master/geojson-counties-fips.json') as response:
    counties = json.load(response)
    
#import libraries
import pandas as pd
import plotly.express as px
 

fig = px.choropleth(df_mover, geojson=counties, 
                    locations='my_zip', 
                    locationmode="USA-states", 
                    color='switcher_flag',
                    range_color=(10000, 100000),
                    scope="usa"
                    )
fig.update_layout(margin={"r":0,"t":0,"l":0,"b":0})
fig.show()
```

I'm simply trying to pass in data from my dataframe named df_movers, which has two fields: my_zip and switcher_flag. When I run this in a Jupyter notebook, it just runs and runs; it never stops. I'm only trying to plot 25 records, so it's not like there's too much data here. Finally, my_zip is data type object. Any idea what could be wrong here?

Comment: can you upload a sample of your dataframe? you can paste the output from `df.head(20).to_dict()` into your question – this will help us try to reproduce the issue you're having in your Jupyter notebook (i am going to assume you already tried restarting it)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you did not provide any user data, I tried your code with data including US zip codes from [here](https://simplemaps.com/data/us-zips). I think the issue is that you don't need to specify the location mode. I specified county_fips for the location and population for the color fill.

```
import plotly.express as px
from urllib.request import urlopen
import json
with urlopen('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/plotly/datasets/master/geojson-counties-fips.json') as response:
    counties = json.load(response)
    
#import libraries
import pandas as pd
us_zip = pd.read_csv('data/uszips.csv', dtype={'county_fips': str}) 

fig = px.choropleth(us_zip,
                    geojson=counties, 
                    locations='county_fips', 
                    #locationmode="USA-states", 
                    color='population',
                    range_color=(1000, 10000),
                    scope="usa"
                    )
fig.update_layout(margin={"r":0,"t":0,"l":0,"b":0})
fig.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Yeah, that definitely works! Thanks a lot!!